# When is the __prepare__ method of a metaclass excuted and what uses its return value?

Tags: python, class, metaclass, dynamic-class-creation

[PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/#example) has the following example of using the `__prepare__` method of a metaclass (`print` statements are mine):

```
# The custom dictionary
class member_table(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.member_names = []

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'in __setitem__{key, value}')
        # if the key is not already defined, add to the
        # list of keys.
        if key not in self:
            self.member_names.append(key)

        # Call superclass
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

# The metaclass
class OrderedClass(type):

    # The prepare function
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases): # No keywords in this case
        print('in __prepare__')
        return member_table()

    # The metaclass invocation
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        print('in __new__')
        # Note that we replace the classdict with a regular
        # dict before passing it to the superclass, so that we
        # don't continue to record member names after the class
        # has been created.
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))
        result.member_names = classdict.member_names
        return result

print('before MyClass')

class MyClass(metaclass=OrderedClass):
    print('in MyClass 1')

    # method1 goes in array element 0
    def method1(self):
        pass
    
    print('in MyClass 2')

    # method2 goes in array element 1
    def method2(self):
        pass
    
    print('in MyClass 3')
```

Running this, prints this:

```
before MyClass
in __prepare__
in __setitem__('__module__', '__main__')
in __setitem__('__qualname__', 'MyClass')
in MyClass 1
in __setitem__('method1', <function MyClass.method1 at 0x7fa70414da60>)
in MyClass 2
in __setitem__('method2', <function MyClass.method2 at 0x7fa70414daf0>)
in MyClass 3
in __new__
```

So it seems like when `MyClass` is executed, execution first goes to the class's metaclass's `__prepare__` method which returns `member_table()` (who/what uses this return value?), then something sets the class's `__module__` and `__qualname__`, then executes the class body, which sets the class's methods (`method1` and `method2`), then the `__new__` method is called with the return value of `__prepare__` as the `classdict` argument value to `__new__` (who/what is passing along this value?).

---

I tried to step through the execution in thonny's debugger, but that threw an error. I also tried stepping through execution in pythontutor.com, but that wasn't granular enough. I `pdb'`ed it, but it was hard to follow what was going on. Finally, I added some `print` statements, which are present in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the `prepare()` is the `namespace` argument that gets passed to `__new__`.  It is the namespace in which the body of the class is evaluated (see [1]).

So within the newly created class, you can see the values of `MyClass.__module__`, `MyClass.__qualname__`, etc because they are being assigned in the namespace object of `MyClass`.

Most uses of metaclasses have no need for `prepare()`, and an ordinary namespace is used.

[1] https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__prepare__#preparing-the-class-namespace

Comment: Thanks. I finally found a link to documentation on this today. Added the link to your answer.